# Python popen script to search for the command running in the process in linux

Tags: python

I am using "popen" to get the process list in linux.Since i am new to python i don't know how to search for my process in the list of processes.Below i am adding my code snippet:

```
import os
p = os.popen('ps -aef',"r")
while 1:
    line = p.readline()
    if not line: break
    print line
```

I want to search whether command "python ./yowsup-cli demos -c config -e" is running or not and if not running run this command.How should I iterate the process to check for this and restart again.
Can anyone help me with the approach.

Comment: you could also have a look at this: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil - on a debian-like system it's the `python-psutil` package.

Answer (score 1):

You could use readlines() and list comprehension instead.
Then your code should look something like this:

```
command_to_run = "python ./yowsup-cli demos -c config -e"
if not any([command_to_run in line for line in p.readlines()]):
    # run your command
```

Note that this would run your command even if a wider command line was specified, such as "python ./yowsup-cli demos -c config -e -a -b -c", but I just didn't find it likely to happen in this case, so that code would do fine.

Comment: I tried this and it worked for me but now i am getting "close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr" error

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use `subprocess` when running linux os commands from within python. Second you should use `grep` to filter the output of your command. `ps` command may return more than one line so stdout should be saved into a list. As an example for your need:

```
import subprocess

def subprocess_cmd(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    proc_stdout = process.communicate()[0].strip()
    return proc_stdout

process_ids = subprocess_cmd("ps -ef |grep python |grep yowsup-cli |grep -v grep |awk '{ print $2 }'")
process_ids_list = process_ids.split('\n')
if process_ids_list == ['']:
    print = 'STOPPED'
else:
    print = 'RUNNING'
```